Fee token with whitelist
Sorry for stupid question.
Fee token is done, when I call transferCheckedWithFee method, token is send and fee is deducted. Now I want some users to not pay the fee. I am using transfer-hook, I used createInitializeTransferHookInstruction method during mint transaction, works fine. But I am confused, when will transfer-hook method will be called?
After using createInitializeTransferHookInstruction method in mint transaction, I am facing error to send tokens.
    const mintLamports = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(mintLen + metadataLen);

    const mintTransaction = new Transaction().add(
    SystemProgram.createAccount({
      fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
      newAccountPubkey: mint,
      space: mintLen,
      lamports: mintLamports,
      programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
    }),
    createInitializeTransferFeeConfigInstruction(
      ---
    ),
    createInitializeMetadataPointerInstruction(
      ---
    ),
    createInitializeTransferHookInstruction(
      mint,
      payer.publicKey,
      program.programId, // Transfer Hook Program ID
      TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
    ),
    createInitializeMintInstruction(
     ---
    ),
    createInitializeInstruction({
      ---
    })
  );
  const newTokenTx = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, mintTransaction [payer,mintKeypair], undefined);

// Now next is to initiate extra account metalist

  const [extraAccountMetaListPDA] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from("extra-account-metas"), mint.toBuffer()],
    program.programId
  );

  const [whiteListPDA] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from("white_list")],
    program.programId
  );

const initializeExtraAccountMetaListInstruction = await program.methods
    .initializeExtraAccountMetaList()
    .accounts({
      mint: mint,
      whiteList: whiteListPDA,
      extraAccountMetaList: extraAccountMetaListPDA,
    })
    .instruction();

  const transaction = new Transaction().add(
    initializeExtraAccountMetaListInstruction
  );

  const txSig = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
    provider.connection,
    transaction,
    [wallet.payer],
    { skipPreflight: true, commitment: "confirmed" }
  );

  const destinationOwner = new PublicKey(
    "AYsLTuntBMwcQQbhHzukATVQmLvVbteNRG6LD2RerLDQ"
  );
  const destinationAccount = await createAssociatedTokenAccountIdempotent(
     ---
  );

// Now next to add a user to whitelist
  const addAccountToWhiteListInstruction = await program.methods
    .addToWhitelist()
    .accounts({
      newAccount: destinationAccount,
      signer: wallet.publicKey,
      whiteList: whiteListPDA,
    })
    .instruction();

  const transact = new Transaction().add(addAccountToWhiteListInstruction);

  const txSig2 = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
    connection,
    transact,
    [wallet.payer],
    { skipPreflight: true }
  );
  
// Now next to call transfer method. Will my transfer-hook be called by this method?
const transferSig2 = await transferChecked(
    connection,
    payer,
    sourceAccount,
    mint,
    destinationAccount,
    owner,
    transferAmount,
    decimals,
    [],
    undefined,
    TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
  );
  console.log("Tokens Transfered:", generateExplorerTxUrl(transferSig2));



Does this answer your question? Need Help with token Program 2022 - solana
